# Why is the essential numerical range defined as $W_e(T) = \bigcap_{K\in \mathcal K(H)} \overline{W(T+K)}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have been introduced to the following definition of the *essential numerical range* of a bounded, linear operator on a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space:
$$W_e(T) := \bigcap_{K\in \mathcal K(H)} \overline{W(T+K)}$$
i.e., the essential numerical range $W_e(T)$ of $T$ is the intersection of the closures of numerical ranges of all compact perturbations of $T$.

- **Why** is the essential numerical range defined in this way, i.e., what motivates this definition and how is it useful? Even in my wildest dreams, I would have no reason to consider compact perturbations of $T$ in order to define $W_e(T)$.

I have noticed that definitions in operator theory on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are often motivated by finite-dimensional analogs, but I'm not able to draw any connections here. Thanks for any insights!

---

*Note:* The numerical range of a (bounded, linear) operator $T\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ is defined as
$$W(T) := \{\langle Tx,x\rangle: x\in \mathcal H, \|x\| = 1 \}$$

Comment: With the caveat that Google searchers are personalised: typing "essential numerical range" into Google shows me the following passage. "The essential numerical range $W_e(T)$ was introduced by Stampfli and Williams for a bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space as the closure of the numerical range of the image of in the Calkin algebra."

Comment: You might also want to add a link to your MSE version of the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527855/why-is-the-essential-numerical-range-defined-as-w-et-bigcap-k-in-mathcal

Comment: My (wild) guess is that the motivation has to do with what happens with the spectrum: the essential spectrum of a bounded op is invariant under self-adjoint compact perturbations. To give an example: if you let $T$ be the compact operator that sends $x_T$ to itself and everything orthogonal to $x_T$ to 0, its numerical range is $[0,1]$, but its essential range is just $\{0\}$. The connection to "finite dimensional" should be read as "the part of the numerical range that _cannot_ be explained by essentially finite dimensional effects".